# Swift | Как определить индекс ячейки, где нажали кнопку?

Tags: swift, tableview

В каждой ячейке таблицы у меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую на следующий viewcontroller передаётся уникальное число из массива:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToRatingModal" {
        guard let dvc = segue.destination as? ModalRatingVC else { return }
        dvc.doctorID = appointments[].doctor.id
    }
}
```

Пробовал tableView.indexForSelectedRow, но приходит nil, так как по факту нажатия на ячейку-то не происходит.

Как можно "определить" индекс ячейки, в области которой произошло нажатие на кнопку?

Comment: Добавьте больше кода: как строите ячейки и как пробрасываете нажатие?

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему с помощью колбека:

```
    cell.buttonTappedHandler = {
        self.doctorID = appointment.doctor.id
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil)
    }
```

И соответственно, где ячейка нужно создать IBAction для кнопки и туда поставить клоужер.

Спасибо ребятам с форума swiftbook за разъяснения.